# Low Disk Space on File System root problem

Tags: filesystem, root

I recently installed elementary on my laptop and in the partition of the system use 50 gb but it took only two days using it and says that the space in root filesystem is full, I do not understand because if the requirements for elementary OS are 15 gb
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Very **dependent upon how the disk is/was partitioned ...** (in a terminal) if you do the following few commands we should be able to determine if it is a "partitioning" issue ... the commands and post your output

- `df -h`
- `grep -v ^# /etc/fstab`

now to determine WHERE the space is going

- `sudo su -`
- `cd /`
- `du -sh * 2> /dev/null`

### Explanations:

`df -h` == a picture of you disk usage by mount point
`grep -v ^# /etc/fstab` == a list of host the "disks" are mounted
`du -sh * 2> /dev/null` == disk used by directory without any error msgs